# How to create block screen with circle loader

Tags: swift, xcode

I am doing an app that does background job that can take some time
I want to show a loader in that time

I want a black screen with a simple loader in the front of it
and show it \ hide it, 
when I do actions in the background

I want to do a simple half black square with loader circle
that also blocks presses to the screen

Like in this picture:

[image]

How can I achieve that and that ?

Comment: Are you willing  to use some library ?

Comment: sure if there is library that can do that, but i think it should be fairly easy to use without a library no ?

Comment: its easy but library give you more flexibility and well tested code. 
https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

Comment: Nothing gives more flexibility and the guarantee of well testing than coding it yourself.

Comment: @Rizwan do you know how to make that SVProgressHUD on full screen ? (it's only on a small square at the moment)

Comment: There is a property that you need to set. I will check and update

Comment: Thanx Rizwan i'll wait thnx !

Comment: @ChiefMadog - check the answer below for the details of how to use this library, to achieve what you need.

Comment: @ChiefMadog - Were you able to successfully do it.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer**

Since the OP wanted an example code. Hence the updated answer. Hope everyone gets to learn something or the other out of it.

To start with, I created a subclass of UIView and named it `PSOverlaySpinner` and it looks something like below:

```
import UIKit

class PSOverlaySpinner: UIView {

    //MARK: - Variables
    private var isSpinning: Bool = false

    private lazy var spinner : UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.white)
        spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        return spinner
    }()

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle Functions
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.8)
        self.isSpinning = false
        self.isHidden = true
        createSubviews()
    }

    deinit {
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func createSubviews() -> Void {
        self.addSubview(spinner)
        setupAutoLayout()
    }

    // MARK: - Private Methods
    private func setupAutoLayout() {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            spinner.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            spinner.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Public Methods
    public func show() -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if !self.spinner.isAnimating {
                self.spinner.startAnimating()
            }
            self.isHidden = false
        }
        isSpinning = true
    }

    public func hide() -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.spinner.isAnimating {
                self.spinner.stopAnimating()
            }
            self.isHidden = true
        }
        isSpinning = false
    }
}
```

Now move onto the ViewController that you want to add this overlay view to. Since I create my views programmatically, I will show how to do it the same way, but you can easily do it via storyboard or xibs.

**Step 1 : Initialize**

```
public lazy var spinnerView : PSOverlaySpinner = {
    let loadingView : PSOverlaySpinner = PSOverlaySpinner()
    return loadingView
}()
```

**Step 2 : Add as a subview**

```
self.view.addSubview(spinnerView)
```

**Step 3 : Set constraints**

```
spinnerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
spinnerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
spinnerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
spinnerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Step 4 : To show PSOverlaySpinner**

```
spinnerView.show()
```

**Step 5 : To hide PSOverlaySpinner**

```
spinnerView.hide()
```

That is it!!

If you want you can go ahead and modify the `PSOverlaySpinner` as per your needs. For example, you might want to add a UILabel below the spinner indicating him of the type of action taking place and so on.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

**Old Answer**

If you wish to do it manually then create a UIView with the its frame matching self.view.bounds, with 0.5-0.7 alpha and black background color. Add UIActivityIndicator as its subview constrained to its center. For a spinner specific to the image you will have to use the open sourced spinners made available. A couple of them can be found [here](https://github.com/nspavlo/MaterialActivityIndicator). Once done add this view as the topmost subview in self.view.

Comment: @ChiefMadog Updated the answer mate. Hope it is sufficiently clear. Let me know if you have issues implementing the same.

Answer (score 3):

First create one UIView which you will put in front of your LogIn view. Then add UIActivityIndicatorView to the created UIView.

```
let loadingIndicatorView = UIView()
let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
```

Now the loadingIndicatorView should have same frame size as your LogIN view. For color you can set your own color with alpha as you want to show LogIn content too. Initially keep it hidden and whenever you want to show it unhide it.

```
loadingIndicatorView.frame = view.frame
loadingIndicatorView.backgroundColor = .gray
loadingIndicatorView.isHidden = true
```

Now setup activityIndicatorView, it should be shown at centre,

```
activityIndicatorView.center = CGPoint(
        x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2,
        y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2
)
```

You can set some color to the indicator,

```
activityIndicatorView.color = .white
activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

Now add this activityIndicatorView to loadingIndicatorView and loadingIndicatorView to LogIn View.

```
 loadingIndicatorView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
 view.addSubview(loadingIndicatorView)
```

Lastly for showing do,

```
loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
loadingIndicatorView.isHidden = false
```

And for hiding,

```
loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
loadingIndicatorView.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import this library [SVProgressHUD](http://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD) and then set few properties like as follows:

```
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultStyle(SVProgressHUDStyle.dark)
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(.clear)
SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(.white)
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.black)

SVProgressHUD.show()
//SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading something, Loading something,Loading something ...")
```

This will produce same UI output as needed by you in OP. You can find a running sample at my repository ([TestPreLoader](https://github.com/virtualrizwan/TestPreLoader))